# Why is my message not getting displayed in React Native FlatList?

Tags: react-native

Im making a dating app in react native and im using FlatList to display messages. I implemented `inverted` and `onEndReached` props and messages are getting fetched when scrolling up no problem. but when sending a message, (im using socket.io-client with my nodejs server), the new message does not get displayed. Here is my code:

sendMessage func

```
  const sendMessage = async () => {
    if (!currentConversation) return;
    if (isUserBlocked(getRecipient(currentConversation))) return;
    if (isRecipientBlocked(getRecipient(currentConversation)._id)) return;

    if (!newMessage.trim()) return;

    if (user && currentConversation) {
      const v4 = uuid.v4();
      const message = {
        text: newMessage,
        user,
        uuid: v4,
      };

      socket.emit("message", {
        message: { ...message, conversation: currentConversation },
      });

      socket.emit("conversation", {
        userId: getRecipient(currentConversation)._id,
        message: { ...message, conversation: currentConversation },
      });

      setNewMessage("");

      await (await HttpClient()).post(config.SERVER_URL + "/api/message/send", {
        ...message,
        conversationId: currentConversation._id,
      });
    }
  };
```

useEffect to get new Message
the setMessages() func doesnt work

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (message) => {
      const conversationIndex = conversations.findIndex(
        (c) => c._id === message.conversation._id
      );
      if (conversationIndex >= 0) {
        const _conversations = [...conversations];
        message.conversation.latestMessage = message.text;
        _conversations.splice(conversationIndex, 1);
        _conversations.unshift(message.conversation);
        setConversations(_conversations);
        setDefaultConversations(_conversations);
      }
      if (message.conversation._id !== currentConversation._id) return;

      console.log(message.text); //works
      setMessages([...messages, { ...message }]); //doesnt work
    };
    socket.on("message", handler);

    return () => {
      socket.off("message", handler);
    };
  }, [messages]);
```

flatlist

```
             <FlatList
                onEndReached={() =>
                  getMessages(currentConversation, messages.length)
                }
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
                inverted
                data={messages}
                renderItem={(message) => (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      padding: 5,
                      justifyContent: isOwnMessage(message.item)
                        ? "flex-end"
                        : "flex-start",
                    }}
                  >
                    <View
                      style={{
                        padding: 10,
                        backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
                        marginBottom: 5,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        maxWidth: "50%",
                      }}
                    >
                      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                        {message.item.user.displayName}
                      </Text>
                      <Text>{message.item.text}</Text>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
                        {moment(message.item.createdAt).fromNow()}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.uuid}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The new message WAS being added, but to the top, due to the inverted property. So I just changed the `setMessages` to first include the message, and then the rest of the messages.